# TableView cells returning empty Swift Xcode6

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am writing a program where the users can send '*tweets*'. In each table cell there is going to be the '*tweet*' text, a label showing the `username` of the user who posted it, and another label for the `timestamp`.

The code to show the '*tweet*' itself is working fine, so I left the code for that out. However the code below is where I am trying to get the `username` and `timestamp` but when I run the program it does not work. There is no compiler error and the app does not crash, it just all of a sudden returns all empty cells. Not even the '*tweet*' text appears (which was working perfectly before I tried to add the `username` and `timestamp`).

There is no error message shown by the debugger, although it does say that the break point is on line 153 (near the bottom of my code where I have left a comment)

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:TextTableViewCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as TextTableViewCell     

    var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    cell.timestampLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(post.createdAt)

    var findPoster:PFQuery = PFUser.query()
    findPoster.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: post.objectForKey("posted_by").objectId)

    findPoster.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in
        if error == nil{      //*******Breakpoint here********
            let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as PFUser
            cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username

        }
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

**UPDATE:**
This code was working with Xcode beta 6, but now it is not, which of course means it is something new in the most recent version in the language.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why nothing was showing. Every outlet in my program was unconnected... Not sure why though as they were connected and everything was working when I was using beta 6. I definitely didn't manually go and un connect every outlet so I'm not sure why this happened? Maybe it is a bug in the latest version of Xcode? I've had nothing but problems with every upgrade. Hopefully this can help anyone who is in a similar situation.